# Update nested state in reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to update nested data in my reducer. Using the following action, I am returning an array map in my reducer. However my state doesn't change:

```
case "SUBMIT_ANSWER":
        const { current, results, completed } = action.data;
        return state.map(video =>
            video.id === action.id
                ? { ...video, current, results, completed }
                : video
        );
```

Action:

```
{
   type: "SUBMIT_ANSWER", data: {…}}
   data:
   completed: false
   current: 1
   id: 142
   results: {correctAnswers: 1, score: 5}
}
```

Data that needs updating:

```
{ 
   videos: [{
    bookMarked: false
    completed: false
    correctScore: 5
    current: 0
    description: "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>↵"
    iconPath: "require('../assets/images/venepuncture.png')"
    id: 142
    preview: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut"
    questions: (15) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
    results: {score: 0, correctAnswers: 0}
    title: "Venepuncture"
    totalScore: 50
    youtubeVideo: "cxcxcx"
}
......
]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume the following nested state :

```
{
    itemA: 'bla',
    name: [
       {a: 2, b:3, value:'John', lannguages:['pt','en']}
    ],
    obj:{
        obj2:{
            nestedArray : [1,2,3]
        }
    }

}
```

Now let's assume you want to update the `nestedArray` prop uppon an `UPDATE_ARRAY` action, passing a number as `action.data` to be concat:

```
switch(action.type){
    case 'UPDATE_ARRAY': return{
        ...state,
        obj:{
            ...state.obj,
            obj2:{
                ...state.obj.obj2,
                nestedArray : state.obj.obj.nestedArray.concat(action.data)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just use the spread operator in the right order and you should be fine!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that

```
var state = {
    videos: [...]
}
```

you must use `Object.assign` to get a new state object (**do not mutate original state**) with the desired changes

```
const { current, results, completed } = action.data;
return Object.assign({}, state, {
   videos: state.videos.map(...)
});
```